# Install specific package from specific index

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have built a package (let's call it *mypackage*) that depends on a well-known third-party module (namely *pandas*), available on PyPi.
I've uploaded mypackage on a custom PyPi-like server (*pypicustom*). I'm struggling to install it on environments where all I have access to is a mirror to PyPi (let's call it *pypiproxy*).

```
pip install --index-url http://custompypi/ mypackage
```

does not work as *pandas* can't obviously be found.

```
pip install --index-url http://pypiproxy/ --extra-index-url http://custompypi/ mypackage
```

works until somebody uploads a package named *mypackage* on PyPi.

Closest I could come with is:

```
pip install --index-url http://custompypi/ --no-dependencies mypackage
pip install --index-url http://pypiproxy/ --extra-index-url http://custompypi/ mypackage
```

which does not feel right.

Any idea?

Comment: `pip` has no protection from package spoofing. At my previous job, I used `devpi` that can proxy  PyPI with spoofing protection as custom index, and installed from it exclusively (via `—index-url=http://customindex`).

Comment: In the Perl world we have scripts that help with creating a local mirror of the latest versions of all of the public packages (a "MiniCPAN") and then injecting locally-built packages into that, so that you can point installers at a *single* source and avoid this problem. Does similar tooling exist for Python?

Comment: @hobbs: Yes (https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/index-mirrors-and-caches/#complete-mirror-with-bandersnatch – hoefling mentioned devpi in the comment above), but that’s a very heavyweight solution.

Answer (score 6):

Probably not the answer you’re wanting, but [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/) (a Python dependency/environment tool) handles your requirement really well.

Not only can you configure sources with different priorities but [you can explicitly set the source for a package](https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/#package-source-constraint) so then when you do a  `poetry install` it pulls all the dependencies from the sources you specify. A pyproject.toml for your example:

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
...
mypackage = { version = "^0.22", source = "custompypi" }

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "custompypi"
url = http://custompypi/
priority = "explicit"

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "pypi-proxy"
url = http://pypiproxy/
priority = "default"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been using an incremental improvement over the closest solution the question.

Say the two package index URLs are `A` and `B`, where you want `mypackage` to come from `A` and and its dependencies to come from `B`. In my use case, `A` is [TestPyPI](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-testpypi/) and `B` is PyPI.

Start by installing `mypackage` from `A` without dependies, just as in the question:

```bash
$ pip install --no-deps --index-url 'A' mypackage
```

Then install the dependencies exclusively from `B` with

```
$ pip install --index-url 'B' mypackage | grep 'Requirement already satisfied: mypackage' > /dev/null
```

The added `grep` lets you assert that `pip install` did not attempt to re-install `mypackage` from `B`. If `'Requirement already satisfied: mypackage'` isn't found in `pip install`'s output, the command will exit with status 1. This lets you have some certainty that the `mypackage` you're left with is indeed the one from `A`.

We can also omit `--extra-index-url 'A'` in the second command provided that `mypackage` doesn't depend on any additional distributions from `A`. `pip install` is OK with resolving dependencies for an already-installed distribution that can't be found in a configured index.

If you want to preserve the stdout of the second command (say for a workflow log), you can [add a pipe to `tee /dev/tty`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/178752/564341) between `pip install` and `grep`.

Comment: Just installing a package is enough to run malicious code – it could even print out the pattern you’re grepping for.

Comment: @Ry- True, though a few things would have to go wrong (right?) for that kind of attack to play out. You'd need pip to actually attempt to re-install the package in the first place, which I'm not sure can ever happen unless the first command failed (which can be detected) or if `--upgrade-strategy/-U` is somehow set. The grep is more sanity-check and documentation than safeguard.

Comment: As far as malicious code skirting the `grep` by printing the same pattern, that could probably be migrated by just checking only the first line from pip's output. Getting the malicious code to actually print that pattern would also be a bit tricky too, since AFAIK build scripts that get run during `pip install` are always run in subprocesses which can't write directly to `pip`'s stdout. I suppose the build script could exit with non-zero status to convince pip to write its stdout for it, but then the overall pip install would fail, which could be detected.