# How to install specific package from specific repo? (requirements.txt)

Tags: python, requirements.txt

I have say following packages in requirements.txt

```
abc
def
ghj
```

I would like to install only ghj from a specific repo. Is that possible?

If I specify `--extra-index-url <link>` in requirements.txt, then it install ghj from that specific repo, but then it also installs abc or def from that repo.

Basically I have two repos, A and B. Only B hosts ghj, but B also can host abc and def. But I want abc and def to come from A only.

A is standard repo. B is private repo (but I cannot control what is installed there).

Comment: can you have two files, one for each repo? Can you get the url directly to `ghj`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71830817/install-specific-package-from-specific-index

Answer (score 0):

Requirements files are primarily concerned with *what* to install (i.e. package names/versions), not *where* to install them from (i.e. which package index). They do not support specifying a different index per-package ([#12233](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12233)). You may separate the per-index requirements into different files, and then you have to install them with separate pip invocations too:

```
# requirements-a.txt
abc
def
```

and

```
# requirements-b.txt
ghj
```

Then:

```
pip install -r requirements-a.txt
pip install -r requirements-b.txt

# warning: this looks tempting but will NOT work correctly!
#   pip install -r requirements-a.txt -r requirements-b.txt
```

The exception to this rule is for [urlspec](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/#examples) requirements, which do allow you to specify *where* to install a package from. Maybe they can help you, if you're happy to install from a source tag directly rather than to install from a wheel/sdist.