# Can a pyproject.toml file list an external dependency (i.e. .whl file) with a >= rather than an exact version?

Tags: python, pyproject.toml

I would like to include some external dependencies in my package's pyproject.toml file.

One of these 'external' dependencies is another package (which here I will just call 'A') that is an internal business package, and which therefore we do not plan on hosting on Github or PyPI. Currently, this package's .whl files are hosted internally, and can be installed using pip.

The other package is blpapi, which Bloomberg recommends to install by doing

```
pip install --index-url=https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple blpapi
```

Currently, I would write

```
blpapi @ https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple/blpapi/blpapi-3.23.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
```

and

```
A @ url-for-A/A-SPECIFIC_VERSION_NUMBER-py3-none-any.whl
```

but this has the obvious limitation of specifying a specific version to download, rather than taking the latest version according to some constraint, i.e. as one might do for pandas

```
pandas >= 1.5.3, < 2
```

How can I/is it currently possible to incorporate such unrestrictive external dependency version requirements in the pyproject.toml file, i.e. something like the below?

```
A @ url-for-A/A >= 4.2.1
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71830817/11082165

Comment: @Brian61354270 - thank you for this. I do not particularly want to install poetry, as I have had issues with it in the past and so far have not really needed any functionality beyond using setuptools with pyproject.toml. Is there definitely no way to just do something like 'blpapi @ https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple/blpapi/ >= 3.23.0' with setuptools and pyproject.toml?

Comment: Place abstract dependency notations in the packaging metadata (in `pyproject.toml` `project.dependencies` list) and concrete dependency notations in a `requirements.txt` file: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/

Comment: Use something like [simpleindex](https://github.com/uranusjr/simpleindex) or any [other more involved package index proxy/mirror](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/index-mirrors-and-caches/).