# 'No matching distribution found for setuptools' while building my own pip package

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi, python-packaging

I am building a Python package using setuptools. This is the basic structure:

```
/path/to/project/
    ├── myproj/                    
    │   ├── __init__.py             
    │   └── my_module.py       
    ├── pyproject.toml              
    ├── setup.cfg                   
    └── ## other stuff
```

This is the content of `pyproject.toml`

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools",
    "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

and this is the content of `setup.cfg`

```
[project]
name = "my_package"
author = 'my name'
requires-python = ">=3.8"
keywords = ["one", "two"]
license = {text = "BSD-3-Clause"}
classifiers = []
dependencies = []

[metadata]
version = attr: my_package.__version__

[options]

zip_safe = True
packages = my_package
include_package_data = True
install_requires =
    matplotlib==3.6.0
    spacy==3.7.2
    networkx>=2.6.3
    nltk>=3.7
    shapely>=1.8.4
    pandas>=1.3.5
    community>=1.0.0b1
    python-louvain>=0.16
    numpy==1.23.4
    scipy


[options.package_data]
my_package = ## pointers to data

[options.packages.find]
exclude =
    examples*
    demos*
```

I can run successfully `python -m build`. Then, if I `pip install` it locally, i.e., pointing directly to the `.tar` file that was built, I can install it.

However, if I upload it to test.pypi and then I `pip install` it from test.pypi, I get the following error:

```
pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3 lines of output]
      Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Looks like an issue with setuptools, but I really cannot figure out how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, if I upload it to test.pypi and then I pip install it from test.pypi

I assume this means you're using `--index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/`, which is confirmed by the build output `Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/`. That tells pip to use TestPyPI *exclusively* as the package index. You will only be able to install packages that are published to TestPyPI, which [setuptools is not](https://test.pypi.org/search/?q=setuptools).

If you want to install packages from both TestPyPI and PyPI during the same `pip install` command, you can use `--extra-index-url` instead of `index-url`. Note that this means that *any* package can be installed from either TestPyPI or PyPI, with no guarantees as to which packages come from which index. If you want install particular packages from particular indices (e.g. `my_package` from TestPyPI, and everything else from PyPI), you can try the solutions from [Install specific package from specific index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71830817/11082165).

Comment: thank you very much! I honestly haven't thought about this. The `--extra-index-url` solution works, I can successfully install the package. I will refer to the other solutions  you suggest to perform other tests before moving to pypi.